# UIPickerview done button not working, even its not calling selector method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I am creating `UIPickerView` `programatically` and added a custom `button`, when the user pressed the `button`, the `picker` will not display. But when I pressed the `button`, it didn't even call its `selector` `method`. I know this question have many answers on this website, but it didn't solved my problem.

```
-(void) funtion
{
self.myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
self.myPickerView.dataSource = self;
self.myPickerView.delegate = self;
self.myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
self.myPickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 417, 320, 151);
[self.myPickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

UIToolbar *toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
[toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                 target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(donePressed:)];
toolBar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barButtonDone,nil];
barButtonDone.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];


[self.myPickerView addSubview:toolBar];

[self.view addSubview:self.myPickerView];

}

-(void)donePressed:(id)sender
{
      [self.myPickerView endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: where you call this method **funtion**

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik its in viewdidload

Comment: where you used this picker view for textfield or some where else

Comment: i used it on a button, when I pressed that button, pickerview is displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for example I add this

**Step-1**

Create the One `UIPicker`,`UItextField` and NSArray for load the details

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>
{

UITextField *myTextField;
UIPickerView *myPickerView;
NSArray *pickerArray;
}

@end
```

**Step-2**

on your `ViewDidLoad` call the picker method like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[self addPickerView];
}
```

**Step-3**

```
create the picker, textfield and done button

-(void)addPickerView{
pickerArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Chess",
               @"Cricket",@"Football",@"Tennis",@"Volleyball", nil];
myTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:
               CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 30)];
myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
myTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
myTextField.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:myTextField];
[myTextField setPlaceholder:@"Pick a Sport"];
myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
myPickerView.dataSource = self;
myPickerView.delegate = self;
myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                               target:self action:@selector(done:)];
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:
                      CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-
                                 myPickerView.frame.size.height-50, 320, 50)];
[toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         doneButton, nil];
[toolBar setItems:toolbarItems];
myTextField.inputView = myPickerView;
myTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

}
```

**Step-4**

if user press the Done Button resign the picker

```
-(void)done:(id)sender
{

[myTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

**Step-5**

PickerView Delegate methods

```
#pragma mark - Picker View Data source
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
return [pickerArray count];
}

#pragma mark- Picker View Delegate

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:
(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
[myTextField setText:[pickerArray objectAtIndex:row]];
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:
(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
return [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

here I attached the [**sample project**](https://www.sendspace.com/file/no1jh1)

**Sample Output like**

[image]

**Update**

if you are used the button hidden the pickerview use this

```
-(void)donePressed:(id)sender
{
  [self.myPickerView removeFromSuperview];

}
```

when you pressed the button call this method

```
[self funtion];
```

Comment: the problem i was facing that the toolbar is placed behind the pickerview, thats why it didn't detect the touch event. your solution helped me. thanks

Comment: The key from this was to set the picker as the `inputView` and the toolbar as the `inputAccessoryView`. Don't set the toolbar as a subview of the picker.

Comment: When done is pressed, `[myPickerView removeFromSuperview]` didn't work well. I tried instead `[self.view endEditing:YES]` and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Add done button like this:-

```
UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 50);
[doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(donePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:logoButton];
toolBar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:barButtonDone,nil];
barButtonDone.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[self.myPickerView addSubview:toolBar];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add toolbar as inputAccessoryView to the text field,

```
// Tool bar

UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,35)];
pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

// Bar button

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneButtonTapped:)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

[pickerToolbar setItems:@[flexSpace,doneButton]];

self.selectedLockerTextFiled.inputAccessoryView = pickerToolbar;
self.selectedLockerTextFiled.inputView = picker;
```